# Laravel PHP8 Coverage doesn't recognise constructor with promoted properties

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, php-8

I am using the **PHP 8** constructor property promotion feature in my **Laravel 8** project. It works perfectly, but when you try to test it, the **coverage does not consider the constructor as tested**.

Packages:

- laravel/framework: ^8.12
- phpunit/phpunit: ^9.5

```
public function __construct(
        private int $id,
        private string $name
    ) {
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

Coverage Report:

[image: Coverage Report]

Comment: Did you check that this feature is supported in your version of PHPUnit?